# To review the size of an pie chart in relation with its frame and other elements in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

By running this code,

```
g <- ggplot(results_table, aes(x = "", y =Pct*100, 
           fill = factor(results_table$Criteria, as.character(results_table$Criteria))),width = 0.5) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title=element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(),, 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)) + 
  theme(
    legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.key.width = unit(0.7, "lines"), #smaller squares
    legend.margin=margin(l = 40, unit='pt'),
    legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(r = 60, unit = "pt"))) +
  xlab("") +  
  ylab("") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.65, y = 100-(Pct*100/2 + c(0, cumsum(Pct*100)[-length(Pct*100)])),
                label = paste0(sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%")),
            size = 3.2) +
  labs(title = gTitle)
```

we have the following image :

[image]

The pie sounds like small and I would like to enlarge it, while the rest has to remain the same (for example, by reducing the space between the pie and its legend).

Comment: Why not just increase the size of the plot window?

Comment: Actually, I have to include the frame in a small area in a standard report to send to the client, then I would like that the title and the legend remain the same, but the pie has to be proportionally larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just resizing the plot window with your exact code, I get this:

[image]

With a couple of little tweaks, in particular, making the top margin of the legend box a negative value, I get this:

```
ggplot(results_table, aes(x = "", y = Pct*100, 
           fill = factor(Criteria, as.character(Criteria))), width = 0.5) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.65, 
                y = 100-(Pct * 50 + c(0, cumsum(Pct*100)[-length(Pct*100)])),
                label = paste0(sprintf("%0.1f", round(Pct*100, digits = 1)),"%")),
            size = 3.2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Palcolor) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position   = "bottom", 
      legend.title      = element_blank(), 
      axis.title.x      = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y      = element_blank(), 
      panel.border      = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid        = element_blank(),
      axis.text         = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks        = element_blank(), 
      plot.title        = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = -10),
      plot.margin       = margin(-50, 0, -20, 0),
      legend.key.height = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
      legend.key.width  = unit(0.7, "lines"),
      legend.box.margin = margin(t = -80, b = 0, l = 40, unit='pt'),
      legend.text       = element_text(margin = margin(r = 60, unit = "pt"))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)) + 
  labs(title = gTitle)
```

I got this:

[image]

---

**Data inferred from question**

```
results_table <- structure(list(Pct = c(0.627, 0.119, 0.09, 0.06, 0.06, 0.03, 
  0.015), Criteria = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L), 
  .Label = c("Above Market (60th to 74th Percentile)", 
  "At Market (50th Percentile)", "Below Market (44th Percentile or Lower)", 
  "No Policy", "Slightly Above Market (51st to 59th Percentile)", 
  "Slightly Below Market (45th to 49th Percentile)", 
  "Well Above Market (75th Percentile or Higher)"), class = "factor")), 
  row.names = c(1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Palcolor <-  c("#702082", "#00a0d2", "#00c389", "#63666a", 
               "#c110a0", "#ffb81c", "#be57d5")

gTitle <- "Market Positioning of Annual Base Salary for Sales\nEmployees"
```

Comment: Hi, Thansk you for your reply. Sounds like what I want. I'm going to check your solution and keep you posted.

Comment: Your solution is fine, except that the title was out f the frame, but I have reviewed the parameters' values as such a way that it is available now. Thank you very much !